# How to use Advanced Search Queries in Spotify?

Tags: javascript, spotify

I'm trying to use the "advanced query syntax" as linked in the Search documentation.

But there doesn't come anything back! My search code adds 'artist:"' in front of the search term and '"' at the end.

But for example The Offspring doesn't return a single result. In the Spotify intern message box it does work and even if you add the search term in the search box in the upper left corner of the Spotifiy application it returns results.

My code looks like that:

```
  var search = (new models.Search('artist:"' + searchWord + '"', {
           'localResults'    : models.LOCALSEARCHRESULTS.IGNORE,
            'searchArtists'   : false,
            'searchAlbums'    : false,
            'searchTracks'    : true,
            'searchPlaylists' : false,
            'pageSize'        : 10,
            'searchType'      : models.SEARCHTYPE.SUGGESTION                
        }));

  search.observe(models.EVENT.CHANGE, searchResultObserver);
```

The code returns results for searchWord and adds them in my UI, but for artist:"search terms" it keeps blank.

Why? Is that a license issue that I'm not allowed to get the "good" search results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`models.SEARCHTYPE.SUGGESTION` doesn't seem to work with advanced queries. Try `models.SEARCHTYPE.NORMAL` instead.

Comment: You're correct. I ended up using two search objects. A normal and a suggestion type to ensure the user gets results while he's typing.